# Find an element in xml by its inner text

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am trying to search an xml element from the root element of the file on the basis of inner text. i have tried this but didnt work:

```
rootElRecDocXml.SelectSingleNode("/ArrayOfRecentFiles[name='"+mFilePath+"']");
```

I know the old school way to traverse all file element by element but i dont want to do that.

Please note that: my root element name is `ArrayOfRecentFiles` and my child element name are `RecentFile`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We'd need to see the xml; @Lee gives the correct approach here, so something like:

```
var el = rootElRecDocXml.SelectSingleNode(
          "/ArrayOfRecentFiles/RecentFile[text()='"+mFilePath+"']");
```

(taking your edit/reply into account)

However! There are lots of gotchas:

- the query will be case-sensitive
- white-space will be significant (so `<foo>abc</foo>` is different to `<foo> abc[newline]</foo>` etc - ditto carriage return)
- xml namespaces are significant, so you may need `.SelectSingleNode("/alias:ArrayOfRecentFiles[text()='"+mFilePath+"']", nsmgr);`, where `nsmgr` is the namespace-manager

---

To give a complete example, that matches your comment:

```
XmlDocument rootElRecDocXml = new XmlDocument();
rootElRecDocXml.LoadXml(@"<ArrayOfRecentFiles> <RecentFile>C:\asd\1\Examples\8389.atc</RecentFile> <RecentFile>C:\asd\1\Examples\8385.atc</RecentFile>   </ArrayOfRecentFiles>");
string mFilePath = @"C:\asd\1\Examples\8385.atc";
var el = rootElRecDocXml.SelectSingleNode(
    "/ArrayOfRecentFiles/RecentFile[text()='" + mFilePath + "']");
```

Here, `el` is *not* `null` after the `SelectSingleNode` call. It finds the node.

Comment: this is my xml:
<ArrayOfRecentFiles>
   <RecentFile>C:\asd\1\Examples\8389.atc</RecentFile>
   <RecentFile>C:\asd\1\Examples\8385.atc</RecentFile> 
</ArrayOfRecentFiles>

Answer (score 3):

You need to use "text()" to check against the inner text of an element as below.

```
rootElRecDocXml.SelectSingleNode("/ArrayOfRecentFiles[text()='"+mFilePath+"']");
```

Comment: Try this then didn't realise you had an additional child node level rootElRecDocXml.SelectSingleNode("/ArrayOfRecentFiles/RecentFile[text()='"+mFilePath+"']");